# How to add a left vertical sidebar to the default template of a .Net Core Web Application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-core

I want to add a left vertical sidebar to the default bootstrap template of an .Net Core 3.1. This sidebar must be visible only for registered users, after the login.
[ScreenShot of the default .Net Core Web Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuK1n.png)

Here is the code of the _Layout.cshtml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Agalber.Hostel.Backoffice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><img src="~/logoagalber.png" alt="AGALBER" width="102" height="46" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - Agalber.Hostel.Backoffice - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the content of the site.css file.

```html
/* Please see documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification
for details on configuring this project to bundle and minify static web assets. */

a.navbar-brand {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}

/* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */
a {
  color: #0366d6;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: inherit;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are using Asp.net core Identity to login the web site, if that is the case, you could check if `User` or `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true or not, then according to the result to display the sidebar.

Code as below (_Layout.cshtml):

```
<div class="container">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

    <div class="sidenav">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    }
    <div class="main">

        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS style:

```
    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }

    .sidenav {
        width: 130px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 60px;
        left: 10px;
        background: #eee;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 8px 0;
    }

        .sidenav a {
            padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: #2196F3;
            display: block;
        }

            .sidenav a:hover {
                color: #064579;
            }

    .main {
        margin-left: 140px; /* Same width as the sidebar + left position in px */
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }
```

After login success, the result as below :

[image]

If you are not using Asp.net core Identity, you could use ViewData or TempData to store the user information, then, in the layout page, you could use If statement to check whether the ViewData or TempData is null or not, then show the sidebar.

Comment: Thank you, mainly has worked, but I see the elements of the sidebar on horizontal dispose.